# ImageMagick: how to compare images in different folders

Tags: imagemagick

I have three folders, named - actual, expected and difference. I need to compare an image from folder "actual" and "expected" and save the compared image in "difference" folder. When I use the following command, I get "Unable to open image".

```
compare /actual/party_1.png /expected/party_1.png /diff/compare_1.png
```

Comment: Do you really have a directory called `/actual` at the top of your filesystem, or is it just `actual` in the current directory? Likewise with `expected` and `diff`... I am hinting that you may need to drop the slash at the start.

Comment: Yes, I have those 3 directories...The structure is screenshots-->actual, expected, difference

Comment: So, if you run `ls -l /actual/*png` and `ls -l /expected/*png` and `ls /diff`

Comment: And also `which compare`

Comment: I am sorry, i did not get your question or comment "which compare"

Comment: i do see images when i use ls actual/*.png

Comment: Yes, but `/actual/*.png` is *totally different* from `actual/*.png`. The slash at the start means it is an *absolute* path to a directory at the very top (root) of your filesystem, not a path to somewhere within your home directory.

Comment: `which compare` is a command that tells you which `compare` program you are running. What OS are you using?

Comment: i use Mac, but I was able to figure out by using this command ---- compare -metric AE actual/party_1.png expected/party_1.png diff/compare_1.png. It compares the image and adds the compared image in diff folder. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: @familyGuy: If you solved your problem now, you should provide an answer to your own question too! (This is totally within the rules of this website and within the expectations of is community :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the solution by using this command:

```
 compare -metric AE actual/party_1.png expected/party_1.png diff/compare_1.png
```

Comment: That is exactly what my first comment to you suggested.